# Is there one tree of life that stood on each side of the river?

Tags: revelation, translation-philosophy

> On each side of the river stood the tree of life (Rev 22:2 NIV)

At least a minimum of two trees is needed if each side of a river is planted with it.  How is it that the verse speaks of a singular tree?

Comment: King James Bible has the tree of life in Rev 22:2 to be a she, which is noteworthy.  Paul in Gal 4:26 calls New Jerusalem “our mother”.  The synthesis of these two Bible verses would be that the”tree of life” either refer to saved heavenly women, 12 suburbs of New Jerusalem, or both.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there one tree of life that stood on each side of the river?**

Contemporary English Version (CEV)  Footnotes:

22.2 trees: The Greek has “tree,” which is used in a collective sense of trees on both sides of the heavenly river.

Revelation 22:1-3 Contemporary English Version (CEV)

> 2 Then it flowed down the middle of the city’s main street. On each
> side of the river **are trees[a]** that grow a different kind of fruit
> each month of the year. The fruit gives life, and the leaves are used
> as medicine to heal the nations.

Revelation 22:2 NWT

> 2 Down the middle of its main street. On both sides of the river were
> **trees** of life producing 12 crops of fruit, yielding their fruit each month. And the leaves of the trees were for the healing of the
> nations.+

In a similar vision by Ezekiel, he saw every kind of tree growing food on both sides of the river

Ezekiel 47:12  (NET Bible)

> 12 On both sides of the river’s banks, **every kind of tree** will grow
> for food. Their leaves will not wither nor will their fruit fail, but
> they will bear fruit every month, because their water source flows
> from the sanctuary. Their fruit will be for food and their leaves for
> healing.”[a]

Answer (score 0):

I am a strong and absolute proponent of going back to the original language of the scripture.

- εν μεσω της πλατειας αυτης

  - in the midst of its square/broadway/plateau
- και του ποταμου εντευθεν

  - and of the river hence
- και εκειθεν ξυλον ζωης

  - and thence tree of life
- ποιουν καρπους δωδεκα

  - making/producing twelve fruits
- κατα μηνα εκαστον

  - per month each
- αποδιδουν τον καρπον αυτου

  - from producing its fruits
- και τα φυλλα του ξυλου

  - and the leaves of the tree
- εις θεραπειαν των εθνων

  - is therapy/healing of nations

#### εντευθεν usage:

- Lk 4:9 if you are son of god, cast yourself hence down.
- Lk 13:31 be you coming-out and going/leaving, hence that herod wills you be-killed.
- Jn 2:16 !lift! these hence, and not !be-making! my father's house emporium-house.
- Jn 7:3 !go-forth! hence and be-towards unto judea
- Jn 18:36 besides now the kingdom of mine is not hence

#### εκειθεν usage:

- Mt 4:21 and proceeding thence, he saw two others, brothers jacobus the zebedaite and yohanan his brother
- Act 13:4 they descended into seleucia thence set-adrift into cyprus

The translation you read wants to say

> - και του ποταμου εντευθεν και εκειθεν ξυλον ζωης
>
>   - and of the river hence-side and thence-side (is) tree of life

Which is quite a stretch.

Due to the sampled usage examples of `εντευθεν` and `εκειθεν`, it is not unreasonable to accept that the passage actually says,

> in the midst of the plateau and of the river hence, and thence a tree of life which produces 12 fruits each per month

i.e.

> in the midst of the plateau and of the river here, there is a tree of life which produces 12 fruits each per month

Comment: Pls explain downvote.

Comment: Is the Sabbath a thing? Or a person, Cynthia?

Answer (score 0):

And he showed me a river of water of life, bright as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God and of the Lamb in the middle of its street. And on this side and on that side of the river **was** the tree of life, producing twelve fruits, yielding its fruit each month; and the leaves of the tree are for the healing of the nations.

**At least a minimum of two trees is needed if each side of a river is planted with it. How is it that the verse speaks of a singular tree?**

I don't see the precise word "planted" in Rv 22:1-2. Jehovah God **planted a garden** in Eden, in Gen 2:8. And out of the ground Jehovah God caused to grow every tree that is pleasant to the sight and good for food, as well as the tree of life, in 2:9. In Brazil I saw that famous nut tree, so large, branches of which would go back into the ground and plant themselves for its spread.

I believe, in keeping with the symbolism, that it is one tree. Hear, O Israel, Jehovah is our God; Jehovah is **one**. Deut 6:4. For also in one Spirit we were all baptized into one Body, whether Jews or Greeks, whether slaves or free, and **were all given to drink one Spirit**.  1 Cor 12:13. The river of water of life symbolizes the Spirit. One Spirit, even as also you were called in one hope of your calling; one Lord, one faith, one baptism; one God and Father of all, who is over all and through all and in all. One Triune God.

My answer has to do with the kind of tree. The tree of life is a vine tree. It's both in the water and on both sides. I am **the true vine**, and My Father is the husbandman...I am the vine. Jn 15:1, 5. Now on the last day, the great day of the feast, Jesus stood and cried out, saying, If anyone thirsts, let him **come to Me and drink. He who believes into Me**, as the Scripture said, out of his innermost being shall flow rivers of living water. But this He said **concerning the Spirit, whom those who believed into Him were about to receive**; for the Spirit was not yet, because Jesus had not yet been glorified. 7:37-39. But as many as received Him, to them He gave the authority to become children of God, to those who believe into His name. 1:12

Answer (score -1):

Peace.

There is only 1 Tree of Life.

The subject matter in Revelation 22 is about the Spirit of Truth flowing out of the throne of God and of the Lamb.

The “pure river of water of life” is the “faithful and true” words of God (the Word of God spoken in Truth and sincerity) as interpreted by the Lamb …and we are to keep His commandments and sacrifice (Lamb) so that we may enter in to understand.

The Scriptures are to be interpreted correctly and flows as a river in the Spirit of Truth to our hearing ears. He that has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit is saying.  We are then judged by how we respond to what we hear.

It is the “acceptable year of the LORD” that is being spoken of….the 12 months:   the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month (12 months).

All Israel (12 manner of fruits) shall be saved in the “acceptable year of the Lord” (12 months).  The acceptable year of the Lord....the year of Jubilee.

> Isaiah 61:1-3 KJV (1)  ***The Spirit of the Lord GOD is upon me;*** because
>   the LORD hath anointed me to preach good tidings unto the meek; he
>   hath sent me to bind up the brokenhearted, to proclaim liberty to the
>   captives, and the opening of the prison to them that are bound;

It is also the Day of Judgment (the water of life flows from the “throne” of God and of the Lamb).  The acceptable year (12 months) of the Lord is proclaimed….as well as the Day of vengeance towards those who will reject and do evil towards what they hear.

> (2)  **To proclaim the acceptable year of the LORD, and the day of
>   vengeance of our God; to comfort all that mourn;**

“To comfort all that mourn”….Those of His people who will mourn will be able to rejoice in what they hear the Spirit saying.    (*James 4:9-10:  Be afflicted, and mourn, and weep: let your laughter be turned to mourning, and your joy to heaviness.  Humble yourselves in the sight of the Lord, and he shall lift you up*).

His people are to be called the trees of righteousness, the planting of the LORD by the outside nations instead of being spoken evil of like we are in this current time of the “time of the gentiles/nations” (42 months).

The time of the nations (42 months) shall be completed  which ushers  in the “acceptable year of the Lord”.  They …the outside nations…shall glorify God in this coming time of the “acceptable year of the Lord” (the 12 months).

> (3)  *To appoint unto them that mourn in Zion, to give unto them beauty
>   for ashes, the oil of joy for mourning, the garment of praise for the
>   spirit of heaviness; that they might be called trees of righteousness,
>   the planting of the LORD, that he might be glorified.*

Again, Tt is the Day of Judgment (as the water flows from the **throne of God)** and also the acceptable year of the LORD (the year of redemption….the year of Jubilee) …the fruit is yielded every month of that year (12 months).

> Revelation 22: KJV (1)  ***And he shewed me a pure river of water of
>   life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God and of the
>   Lamb.***

On one side of the river is one who will speak the Word of Truth…speaking the Lord’s words of life and spirit and on the other side is one who will respond with words of life and spirit….bearing fruits of righteousness towards what one shall hear….what the Spirit is saying.  They will drink in what is being said in the Spirit of Truth and will respond with fruits of righteousness and not evil.

> (2)  *In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the
>   river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits,
>   and yielded her fruit every month: and the leaves of the tree were for
>   the healing of the nations.*

The “fruit of the righteous” is a tree of life….as on one side of the river one speaks the Word of Truth by the Spirit (the living water) and wins souls (the “fruit”) for God.   They will be productive in the knowledge of God and will win people’s thoughts and hearts for Him.

> Proverbs 11:30-31 KJV (30)  ***The fruit of the righteous is a tree of
>   life; and he that winneth souls is wise.***

If the “first works” (add to your faith virtue; and to virtue knowledge…..etc) are in us and abound, then we will not be barren nor “unfruitful” in the knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ as we shall speak His words of life and spirit to others.

> 2 Peter 1:5-8 KJV (5)  *And beside this, giving all diligence, add to
>   your faith virtue; and to virtue knowledge; (6)  And to knowledge
>   temperance; and to temperance patience; and to patience godliness; (7)
>   And to godliness brotherly kindness; and to brotherly kindness
>   charity. (8)  **For if these things be in you, and abound, they make you
>   that ye shall neither be barren nor unfruitful in the knowledge of our
>   Lord Jesus Christ**.*

The church of Ephesus needed to repent and do the  “first works”  so that they would not be barren nor unfruitful in the knowledge of the Lord.

They that would overcome will be given to eat of the Tree of Life as they would not be barren nor unproductive in His knowledge but would “win souls” for Him.   To be productive with His knowledge is “fruit” of the Tree of Life which can be eaten…to rejoice in being productive.

> Revelation 2:7 KJV (7)  *He that hath an ear, let him hear what the
>   Spirit saith unto the churches; **To him that overcometh will I give to
>   eat of the tree of life, which is in the midst of the paradise of God.***

A “wholesome”….that is, a HEALING ….tongue is a tree of life.  They will show brotherly love towards the speaker of the Word of Truth.  One speaks the Word of Truth and the other responds with words of life.

> Proverbs 15:4 KJV (4)  ***A wholesome tongue is a tree of life: but
>   perverseness therein is a breach in the spirit.***

The “leaves” of the Tree were for the healing of the nations as all who will call (the healing tongue is a tree of life) on the name of the Lord shall be saved/healed.  The “leaves” =  words….as with the mouth confession (leaves) is made unto “salvation”….healing.   Whosoever shall call upon the name of the Lord shall be saved/healed.

> Romans 10:10-14 KJV (10)  *For with the heart man believeth unto
>   righteousness; and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation.
>   (11)  For the scripture saith, Whosoever believeth on him shall not be
>   ashamed. (12)  For there is no difference between the Jew and the
>   Greek: **for the same Lord over all is rich unto all that call upon him.
>   (13)  For whosoever shall call upon the name of the Lord shall be
>   saved.** (14)  How then shall they call on him in whom they have not
>   believed? and how shall they believe in him of whom they have not
>   heard? and how shall they hear without a preacher?*

There will be no more curse…instead of the curse, there will be blessings as all nations shall speak well of us in His name:

> Deuteronomy 28:1-2 KJV (1)  *And it shall come to pass, if thou shalt
>   hearken diligently unto the voice of the LORD thy God, to observe and
>   to do all his commandments which I command thee this day, **that the
>   LORD thy God will set thee on high above all nations of the earth:** (2)
>   And all these blessings shall come on thee, and overtake thee, if thou
>   shalt hearken unto the voice of the LORD thy God.*

His servants shall serve Him when they will hear His voice and will respond by the doing of His commandments.

They shall see His face….as they show that they know Him by the doing of His commandments. They will not respond with evil towards the hearing of the Spirit…the water of life which is the speaking of His true and faithful words in the Spirit of Truth.

> Revelation 22: (2)  *In the midst of the street of it, and on either
>   side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve
>   manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month: and the leaves of
>   the tree were for the healing of the nations. (3)  And there shall be
>   no more curse: but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it;
>   and his servants shall serve him: (4)  **And they shall see his face;**
>   and his name shall be in their foreheads.*

There will be no “night” there….no guile….in the hearing of His true and faithful words.

The Word of God is not being deceitfully handled for unjust gain as those who are of the “night” are doing it currently.   No guile/fraud will be found in the mouths of those who will speak His true and faithful words.   The Lord God gives us His Light…His knowledge…to speak His faithful and true words as we serve Him.

> (5)  ***And there shall be no night there;*** and they need no candle,
>   neither light of the sun; for the Lord God giveth them light: and they
>   shall reign for ever and ever. (6)  And he said unto me, These sayings
>   are faithful and true: and the Lord God of the holy prophets sent his
>   angel to shew unto his servants the things which must shortly be done.

The Tree of Life bares 12 manner of fruits and speaks of ALL Israel being saved in this coming time…in the time of the acceptable year (12 months) of the Lord…. after the “fullness of the nations be come in” as the completion of the time (42 months) of the outside world’s  nations will be up.

> Romans 11:25-27 KJV (25)  *For I would not, brethren, that ye should be
>   ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits;
>   that blindness in part is happened to Israel, **until the fulness of the
>   Gentiles be come in. (26)  And so all Israel shall be saved:** as it is
>   written, There shall come out of Sion the Deliverer, and shall turn
>   away ungodliness from Jacob: (27)  For this is my covenant unto them,
>   when I shall take away their sins.*

The time of the outside nations is referenced in the Bible as  “42 months”….or 1260 days (1260/30 days)…when they speak evil of God and His things and is happening now and reaches an end/fullness of the allotted time.

The “mouth” of the 1st beast in Revelation 13 is the outside nations who speak evil….speaking “great things and blasphemies” as they open their mouth (collectively) to blaspheme God and His holy Name and His tabernacle and those that dwell in Heaven.

The 1st beast is “another Jesus” the antichrist (instead of the true Christ) that is being worshipped  by many earthly-minded church people which causes the outside nations to blaspheme God and His holy name because of what they see going on in the many different churches of fleshly-minded men.   This power was given him to continue 42 months…the time of the outside nations blaspheming which comes to an end….the “fullness of the nations/gentiles” enters in.

> Revelation 13:5-6 KJV (5)  ***And there was given unto him a mouth
>   speaking great things and blasphemies; and power was given unto him to
>   continue forty and two months.*** (6)  **And he opened his mouth in
>   blasphemy against God, to blaspheme his name, and his tabernacle, and
>   them that dwell in heaven**.

Interestingly in Nehemiah 7 we see that the number of the whole congregation together was 42,360 of those who were once in the captivity/exile of Babylon but were finally released.

42 = completion of time (42 months) of the treading down of the outside nations that spoke evil 
360= the acceptable year of the Lord (12 X 30 =360 days)

> Nehemiah 7:66 KJV (66)  The whole congregation together was forty and
>   two thousand three hundred and threescore,

They gathered themselves together as one man (in Christ) into the “street” where the Tree of Life is.  This street was before the “Water Gate”…as the river of the water of life flows from there.

> Nehemiah 8:1-3 KJV (1)  *And all the people gathered themselves
>   together as one man into the street **that was before the water gate;**
>   and they spake unto Ezra the scribe to bring the book of the law of
>   Moses, which the LORD had commanded to Israel.*

Those who will love God and love their brothers (the “law”) are able to hear the Word of God spoken in Truth and sincerity and will enter in to understand.

> (2)  *And Ezra the priest brought the law before the congregation both
>   of men and women, a**nd all that could hear with understanding,** upon the
>   first day of the seventh month.*

God is the Light…and it dawns (the morning) in the heart  until there is no more darkness (midday sun).  They could understand the Scriptures as they did God’s commandments..

> (3)  *And he read therein before the street that was before the water
>   gate from the morning until midday, before the men and the women, and
>   those that could understand; and the ears of all the people were
>   attentive unto the book of the law.*

The people mourned but then rejoiced…as they were able to understand the Word of God.

> Nehemiah 8:8-12 KJV (8)  *So they read in the book in the law of God
>   distinctly, and gave the sense, and caused them to understand the
>   reading. (9)  And Nehemiah, which is the Tirshatha, and Ezra the
>   priest the scribe, and the Levites that taught the people, said unto
>   all the people, This day is holy unto the LORD your God; mourn not,
>   nor weep. For all the people wept, when they heard the words of the
>   law. (10)  Then he said unto them, Go your way, eat the fat, and drink
>   the sweet, and send portions unto them for whom nothing is prepared:
>   for this day is holy unto our Lord: neither be ye sorry; for the joy
>   of the LORD is your strength. (11)  So the Levites stilled all the
>   people, saying, Hold your peace, for the day is holy; neither be ye
>   grieved.*

It was the acceptable year of the Lord…and they rejoiced because they were able to understand the words that were declared unto them….the faithful and true words of God.

> (12)  *And all the people went their way to eat, and to drink, and to
>   send portions, and to make great mirth, because they had understood
>   the words that were declared unto them.*

Blessed are they that do His commandments so that they may have right upon the Tree of Life and may enter in through the gates of the city.

> Revelation 22:14-18 KJV (14)  ***Blessed are they that do his
>   commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may
>   enter in through the gates into the city.***

Outside of that knowledge of God are those who will reject what they hear.

(15)  For without are dogs, and sorcerers, and whoremongers, and murderers, and idolaters, and whosoever loveth and maketh a lie.
(16)  I Jesus have sent mine angel to testify unto you these things in the churches. I am the root and the offspring of David, and the bright and morning star.

One will preach the Word of God in the Spirit inviting them to take of the water of life freely ("come").

The other will hear what is being said will be hospitable ("come") towards the speaker/messenger of His words of life and spirit.

And those who the outside nations are also invited/called to take of the water of life (let him that is athirst come).

> *(17)  And the Spirit and the bride say, Come. And let him that heareth
>   say, Come. And let him that is athirst come. And whosoever will, let
>   him take the water of life freely.*

Answer (score -2):

Rev.22;2. First we must understand what the tree life stands for? The tree of life is the eternal life giving force of God, Romans 5;17-18, just like the tree of the knowledge of good and evil is the eternal separation from God, Romans 5;14. Adams transgression is as a result of eating from the tree of knowledge of good and evil.

When i research on Rev.22;2, all the commentators believe the tree is one kind of specie so it's the same thing,some claim it's the fault of the translators to mention trees instead of tree. Well my insight into this verse is that, the tree of Life is the Lord Jesus Christ and Christ can be physically  present everywhere at the same time since His now glorify and His more of  a spirit being, so the tree of life cannot be many, but one, it might sound far fetch but so is the Spiritual. Genesis 2;9 clearly states two Trees in the garden , tree of life and the tree of knowledge and of good and evil.

That's my humble submission i stand to correction since we're all work in progress, 1 Corinthians 13;9 For we know in part, and we prophesy in part.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Fred.